# Term::TermKey: How to enable wide mouse support?

Tags: perl, terminal, mouseevent, libtermkey

When I run this script, the position of the mouse works up to the column 255 - then the count begins by 0. Does this mean that my terminal does not support `SGR`/mode 1006?
(edited due ak2's answer)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use utf8;
use Term::TermKey qw(FLAG_UTF8 FORMAT_LONGMOD FORMAT_MOUSE_POS);
my $tk = Term::TermKey->new( \*STDIN );
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)' if $tk->get_flags & FLAG_UTF8;

$|++;
print "\e[?1003h";
print "\e[?1006h";

say "Quit with \"q\"";
while( 1 ) {
    $tk->waitkey( my $key );
    say $tk->format_key( $key, FORMAT_LONGMOD | FORMAT_MOUSE_POS );
    last if $tk->format_key( $key, 0 ) eq 'q';
}

print "\e[?1006l";
print "\e[?1003l";
```

Comment: Since there's a growing collection of `libtermkey`-based questions, I feel they ought to be tagged. I lack the requisite amount of reputation (1500) to create a new tab, but perhaps if you'd consider this useful you could create one? I can then go around and retag all the questions. It should be about `libtermkey` itself, rather than the Term::TermKey perl wrapper, but that can be an alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

It means you're not using the very lastest `libtermkey` library yet, the one that supports positions greater than column 255. Possibly because I haven't actually released it yet ;)

I'll let you know once that's up, along with the extra CSI capture support for position reporting, etc..

Also: If you have more `libtermkey`-specific questions, you might want to let me know more directly. E.g. you could email me to let me know you've posted a question; I don't always make a habit of searching them out. :)

---

*Edit 2012/04/26*: I've now released `libtermkey` 0.15 and `Term::TermKey` 0.14, which supports these columns above 255, along with the position report API.

Comment: I retried the script with `Term::TermKey` 0.14 and KDE's Konsole but I don't get a column higher then 255.

Comment: I just retried it again, and it's all working for me. Does this work for you now, or still broken?

Answer (score 1):

Switching on mode 1006 changes the mouse event encoding, but it doesn't actually enable mouse reporting. For that, you'll need to switch on mode 1000 (click and release only), 1002 (click, release and drag), or 1003 (click, release, and any mouse movement).